# Switching between battery and transformer

Tags: power

I want when power goes off my device don't lose power and keep working using battery power, the schematic below is what i end up with:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMRcf3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When power is ON transformer trigger the relay and device will use transformer power, when power is OFF relay will "de-energized" and device will use battery power.

What options do we have to switch between transformer and battery in case of power loss which is simple and easy to do?

Comment: A problem with your circuit is that the relay connects the device back to the relay coil. This will mean the device voltage has to drop to the relay dropout voltage, which could be as low as 25% of rated, before it drops out and switches over to battery. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fndsWI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Top: Relay circuit. D3 ensures that the relay drops out quickly when PSU power is lost. (Coil snubber diode not shown.) Bottom: diode circuit.*

The lower circuit is simpler if:

- The PSU voltage is greater than the battery voltage.
- You don't mind the 0.7 V drop of the diodes.

Comment: I'm new to electronics, can you please explain how the second schematic works? are those normal diodes? is output still 9V or is it 18V?

Comment: @newbie: You should be able to see that both supplies are connected to ground so they can't add to 18 V. (If you put two 9-rung ladders on the ground beside each other you can't get 18-steps high. 9 will be your max.) They're normal diodes and just need to be rated for the maximum voltage and current you require. See if the non-return valve in my article [What is an LED?](http://lednique.com/what-is-an-led/) helps with your understanding of diodes.

Answer (score 2):

- relays must be derated for current between low ESR caps and batteries, just as Motors with low DCR by at least 50% or more due to start curve currents and high arc temps on tungsten, silver alloy contacts for caps and turn-off arcs for motors.
- 2mF may be excessive.!!
- FET Half bridge “ideal diode dual switches”  may be a bit more expensive but longer MTBF
- relays need a comparator to drive coil to choose when power is adequate.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use an ‘or’ diode than a relay. The relay will open up as it switches from one supply to another so you run the risk of interrupting the power when that happens.

There are ICs that do this seamlessly using MOSFETs instead of diodes. These ICs reduce the losses to nearly zero.